# "Attach to Process" using VS Web Developer Express 2010, any other options?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

Looks like "Attach to Process" using VS Web Developer Express 2010 option to debug code not available when it is deployed in IIS. IIS and VS Express 2010 in same server.

After I published on IIS website (local), I want to debug in VSWD express 2010.

What are alternatives or workarounds for this?

Comment: VS Pro perhaps? (I know, not the answer you're hoping for.)

Comment: `throw` a lot of `Exception('here i am!')`'s.

Comment: I don't understand.  You say you want to do X, but then ask for alternatives to X.  Workarounds to what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking to debug your application with something other then Visual Studio, you have a few options.  The first is Fiddler2 (http://fiddler2.com/) which allows you to view all traffic between the client browser and the host server.  Another option is to start logging everything.  This is especially useful for applications where you need to keep an audit trail of user actions.